# no file after writing file in internal storage in android

Tags: java, android, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

No error, data in inputstream and outputstream.
I don't know why I can't find the file after I execute it.
It seems like no file creates with no error.
I added all permissions.

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"`

```
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        ArrayList<String> matches =   bundle.getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        // the recording uri is in getData:
        Uri audioUri = data.getData();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        try {
            InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(audioUri);
            String filename = "testVoice01";
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            try {
                OutputStream output = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    Log.d("output", output.toString());
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                is.close();
                Log.d("fileName", filename.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you looking for your file? If you write it to internal storage you will not see it in a file manager app. (unless you're rooted)

Comment: READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE don't exist as permissions in Android. They have no effect and should be removed from the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**Recreate The Problem**

- To clearly figure out whether something else is causing your file not to be created, and assuming you are not rooted, try creating your file in the sdcard (external storage).
- If you are not rooted, you will not be able to view the file by browsing. You can instead read the file using code and log its content and also remember to catch the exception in case the file does not exist. This will help you know that it was perhaps not created.